# Powershell command to show processs with cpu time 10sec

Tags: powershell

Doing this for college but stuck and hope someone can help,

I need to get powershell command to show running processes on the system with CPU time greater than 10 seconds, and then to display

1. the name
2. CPU time
3. the ID

So far, I got this code:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object { $.cpu -gt 10} | Format-Table -Autosize
```

How to organize it to just show process `Name` , `CPU Time` result and `ID`?

Comment: Ye stupidly i was using . instead of , on name, cpu.   " Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.cpu -gt 10 } | Format-Table Name, Cpu, Id -Autosize " Thanks Guys !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either filter the properties before `Format-Table` with `Select-Object`, or give `Format-Table` the properties to display:

```
... | ft -auto Name,CPU,PID
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this something that you'r looking for?

```
Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.cpu -gt 10} | Format-Table -AutoSize -Property "ProcessName", "CPU", "Id"
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing?

Comment: With this request we will sort\filter output of Get-Process, in order **-Property** "ProcessName", "CPU", "Id" we can change this order as we want